# Visual Studio 2019 - ESLint & AirB&B config

Tags: visual-studio-2019, eslint

Does anyone know who to enable ESLint to work with Airbnb's eslint config?  I can see where the config for visual studio is stored but I'm sure how to enable AirBnb's config.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in `C:\Users\ericr\.eslintrc`, simply add `"extends": ["airbnb"]`.